# FIFO mutex code snippet in LockSupport.java

Tags: java, multithreading, mutex, locks

I am trying to understand `LockSupport.java` and referred to its documentation. In there, it has code snippet, in which the authors have provided a sample of implementing a Mutex using LockSupport#park() and LockSupport#Unpark().

I used that sample and created a program that uses that sample FIFOMutex.

FIFOMutex code (taken from LockSupport.java)

```
package com.example.java.locking.studies.locksupport.from.javadoc;

import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport;

class FIFOMutex {
    private final AtomicBoolean locked = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private final Queue<Thread> waiters = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Thread>();

    public void lock() {
        boolean wasInterrupted = false;
        Thread current = Thread.currentThread();
        waiters.add(current);

        // Block while not first in queue or cannot acquire lock
        while (waiters.peek() != current ||
                !locked.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            LockSupport.park(this);
            if (Thread.interrupted()) // ignore interrupts while waiting
                wasInterrupted = true;
        }

        waiters.remove();
        if (wasInterrupted) // reassert interrupt status on exit
            current.interrupt();
    }

    public void unlock() {
        locked.set(false);
        LockSupport.unpark(waiters.peek());
    }
}
```

Now, I wrote the below program to use FIFOMutex as locking mechanism, code below:

```
package com.example.java.locking.studies.locksupport.from.javadoc;

public class FIFOMutexMainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        FIFOMutex mutex = new FIFOMutex();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Inside thread -> " + Thread.currentThread() + "Before mutex.lock()");
                mutex.lock();
                System.out.println("Inside thread -> " + Thread.currentThread() + "After mutex.lock()");

                for (;;) {

                }
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Inside thread -> " + Thread.currentThread() + "Before mutex.lock()");

                mutex.unlock();
                System.out.println("Inside thread -> " + Thread.currentThread() + "After mutex.lock()");

                for (;;) {

                }
            }
        });

        t1.start();

        Thread.sleep(10);

        t2.start();

        Thread.sleep(100);

        mutex.lock();

        System.out.println("Inside thread -> " + Thread.currentThread() + "will I get printed?");
    }
}
```

Below is the output of this program:

```
Inside thread -> Thread[Thread-0,5,main]Before mutex.lock()
Inside thread -> Thread[Thread-0,5,main]After mutex.lock()
Inside thread -> Thread[Thread-1,5,main]Before mutex.lock()
Inside thread -> Thread[Thread-1,5,main]After mutex.lock()
Inside thread -> Thread[main,5,main]will I get printed?
```

Thread-1 starts and acquires the lock, followed by Thread-2, which invokes unlock(). Main calls lock(). My understanding was that Main will be blocked forever, even though Thread-2 invoked unlock(), as Thread-2 didn't ever invoke lock() (so that way, it was never granted a `permit`).

I am not able to understand this behavior.  If I comment unlock() in Thread-2, then main-thread gets blocked forever.

How is it possible that a thread (in my case Thread-2) calls unlock() (which hasn't previously called lock()) and other thread (in this case main thread) calls lock(), but never gets locked?

Answer (score 0):

If you dig into the source code, the unblock method actually release the CAS lock provided by variable `locked` and unpark the first thread. So if you comment out the invoking of `unlock()`, the CAS lock is not released and the main thread can stay in the while loop forever, which blocks the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

First: the FIFOMutex invokes the

```
Thread current = Thread.currentThread();
```

Meaning the actual thread is taken for validation. That means the most actual thread is considered and that is:

- Thread 1 at first and it issues the lock, then
- Thread 2 is invoked and it issues the unlock.

and that is the reason why the main thread won't hang.
BUT: if you comment the unlock of thread 2 none is done and the main thread hangs. That is very understandable, isn't it?